# NGinx Laravel 4 - 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

```
server {
        listen  80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /home/thinkshare/public/;
        index index.php;

        server_name domain_here;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Here is my current NGinx configuration - I cannot for the life of me figure out what exactly is happening to warrent a 502 Gateway Error on connection, domain or IP direct.  Any thoughts?

*edit*

Removed Domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to finally find the answer at this [link](http://www.nginxtips.com/php5-fpm-sock-failed-13-permission-denied-error/).

Effectively, fastcgi_pass in the nginx file as well as listen in the fpm file needs to be changed to 127.0.0.1:9000.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions for the socket are incorrect and the reason why changing to top solved it

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04 I get this error too. I resolved it by editing the 
`/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

```
user = yourname
group = yourgroup

listen.owner = yourname
listen.group = yourgroup
```

and restart php7.0fpm by the use of `$sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

This error is due to your path isn't in default `/var/www` which is owned by `www-data` when you in other directory, you should set it!